# How can I connect web app with azure virtual linux macine on same azure account?

Tags: web-services, azure, unix, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

In my project I have to get two files (fastq it's Bioinformatics file) from user through HTML form and analyse it through some UNIX program (I used PHP in server side scripting) which is supported only in UNIX OS (I'm just using shell_exec() to run all UNIX program). For now I have implemented it in local host and every thing is working fine.

Now I have to do the same in Azure. I have created a webpage in Azure Web app and I have a UNIX VM in the same account. I want to know how i can connect both for free (I have already seen [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) but they are implementing additional charges).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to deploy your app on Azure WebApps & VM based on Linux and make it works as well as on your local host, which is a PHP app and call some UNIX-like program in shell via PHP method `shell_exec`.

Per my experience, there are two ways to do your deployment.

1. You need to create an instance of Azure WebApps for Linux, which is a Docker container based on Ubuntu. Then, you can install any services you want to deploy your PHP app and directly call the UNIX-like programs via PHP method `shell_exec` without any instance of Azure Linux VM to run the UNIX-like programs.
2. You can use an instance of Azure WebApps which is based on Windows, but it's impossible to run the UNIX-like programs hosted on Azure Linux VM via `shell_exec` method. For calling remote UNIX-like programs on Azure Linux VM, there are two ways to change your PHP app as below.

   2.1. Via PHP methods `ssh2_connect`/`ssh2_auth_password`/`ssh2_exec` to create a ssh session to connect the remote Linux VM and do the SSH authentication to run the UNIX-like program via `ssh2_exec` method, if you had installed PHP extension package `ssh2` on Windows for Azure WebApps. My sample code is as below.

   ```
   <?php
   $host = '<your Azure linux vm host>';
   $port = 22; // First enable the 22 port for Azure Linux VM
   $user='<ssh user>';
   $passwd='<ssh password>';
   $session=ssh2_connect($host, $port);
   if($session)
       echo "connect successfully.\n";
   if(ssh2_auth_password($session, $user, $passwd)) {
       echo $user." login OK.\n";
       $stream=ssh2_exec($session, "pwd");
       stream_set_blocking($stream, true); 
       if ($stream === FALSE) die("pwd failed");
           echo 'pwd: '.stream_get_contents($stream).'<br/>';
   }
   ?>
   ```

   2.2. Or you can create a new PHP app to call the UNIX-like programs on Azure Linux VM to publish a WebService API or a RESTful API for being called by your PHP app on Azure WebApps.

Hope it helps.